# va_arg returning the wrong argument

Tags: c++, c, variadic-functions

With the following code va_arg is returning garbage for the second and third pass through vProcessType.

```
// va_list_test.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <tchar.h>
#include <cstdarg>
#include <windows.h>

void processList(LPTSTR str, ...);
void vProcessList(LPTSTR str, va_list args);
void vProcessType(va_list args, int type);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    LPTSTR a = TEXT("foobar");
    int b = 1234;
    LPTSTR c = TEXT("hello world");
    processList(TEXT("foobar"), a, b, c);
    return 0;
}

void processList(LPTSTR str, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, str);
    vProcessList(str, args);
    va_end(args);
}
void vProcessList(LPTSTR str, va_list args)
{
    vProcessType(args, 1);
    vProcessType(args, 2);
    vProcessType(args, 1);
}

void vProcessType(va_list args, int type)
{
    switch(type)
    {
    case 1:
        {
            LPTSTR str = va_arg(args, LPTSTR);
            printf("%s", str);
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        {
            int num = va_arg(args, int);
            printf("%d", num);
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Is passing a va_list thing not allowed in this way?  The first call to va_arg inside vProcessType returns the expected string.  The second and third time through this function it returns a pointer to the start of the first string, instead of the values expected.

If I hoist the va_arg call to vProcessList, everything seems to work fine.  It only seems when I pass a va_list through a function that I'm getting this behaviour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're passing the same `va_list` each time to `vProcessType()` - in each call to `vProcessType()` you're acting on the first `va_arg` in the list.

So you're always dealing with the `TEXT("foobar")` parameter when calling `vProcessType()`.

Also note that the standard has this to say about passing a `va_list` to another function:

> The object `ap` [of type `va_list`] may be passed as an argument to another function; if that function invokes the `va_arg` macro with parameter `ap`, the value of `ap` in the calling function is indeterminate and shall be passed to the `va_end` macro prior to any further reference to `ap`.

A foot note in the standard indicate that it's perfect OK to pass a pointer to a `va_list`, so what you might want to do is have `vProcessType()` take a pointer to the `va_list`:

```
void vProcessType(va_list* pargs, int type);
```

Comment: ... and this is undefined behavior. The only legal way to make a copy if a `va_list` object is a `va_copy` macro. I.e. it is not exactly correct to say that "you're acting on the first `va_arg` in the list". The behavior is simply undefined.

Comment: /facepalm

Thanks, I've modified vProcessType to vProcessType(va_list* pArgs, int type) instead, and added a "*pArgs = args" at the end of vProcessType.

Seems to have worked.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @AudreyT Windows doesn't seem to have a va_copy macro.  What's the recommended solution here?

Comment: @Jonathan Yee: It depends on your intent (read my answer). In short: if you want *continuous* parsing, you have to pass the `va_list` object *by pointer*, as others already suggested. If you want to start from the same point each time, you have to use `va_copy`, which is C99 macro (not present in C89/90, which is why you don't have it in your compiler).

Comment: @Jonathan Yee: From your example it appears that you need *continuous* parsing, meaning that there's no need for `va_copy` in your case. Simply pass the `va_list` object by pointer.

Comment: @JonathanYee You can simply define the `va_copy` macro yourself on Windows: `#define va_copy(a, b)  memcpy(&(a), &(b), sizeof(va_list))`. On some systems it is defined as `__va_copy`. Use `#ifdef` appropriately.

Answer (score 4):

When you pass the `va_list` object to another function and that another function uses `va_arg` on the corresponding parameter, that `va_list` will have *indeterminate value* in the calling function when the control returns. The only thing you are allowed to do is to apply `va_end` to that `va_list` object.

This is how it is stated in the standard (7.15/3)

> If access to the varying arguments is
>   desired, the called function shall
>   declare an object (generally referred
>   to as `ap` in this subclause) having
>   type `va_list`. The object `ap` may be
>   passed as an argument to another
>   function; if that function invokes the
>   `va_arg` macro with parameter `ap`, the
>   value of `ap` in the calling function is
>   indeterminate and shall be passed to
>   the `va_end` macro prior to any further
>   reference to `ap`.

Don't pass `va_list`objects *by value*. If your intent is to *continue* argument parsing in each consequent sub-function, then you have to pass the `va_list` object *by pointer*.

If you really want to pass your `va_list` object *by value*, i.e. if you want each sub-function to parse from the same point, you have to manually copy your `va_list` object in advance by using the `va_copy` macro. ("In advance" means that you have to make as many copies as you'll need before any sub-function has a chance to do a `va_arg` on it.)

Answer (score 3):

You're passing your `va_list` by value.  Try passing a pointer to the one value instead (or if you wanted a C++ only version, you could use a reference):

```
void vProcessList(LPTSTR str, va_list args)
{
    vProcessType(&args, 1);
    vProcessType(&args, 2);
    vProcessType(&args, 1);
}

void vProcessType(va_list *args, int type)
{
    ...
    LPTSTR str = va_arg(*args, LPTSTR);
    ...
    int num = va_arg(*args, int);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, the C99 standard allows a portable (among C99 implementations) way for a program to run through a va_list more than once.  There isn't any nice portable way to do that in pre-C99 implementations.  What I did when I needed to run through a printf list more than once (for a "center string" function which had to evaluate the arguments once to determine how wide they would be, and then a second time to actually display them) was to examine the compiler vendor's "stdarg.h" and fudge my own implementation of the necessary functionality.

If one wanted a really portable implementation that would work on earlier C compilers, and if one knew in advance the maximum number of passes that would be required, I think one could create an array of va_ptr objects, use va_start on all of them, and then pass the array to the child routine.  Sorta icky, though.

Comment: There's a very easy way to portably run through the arguments more than once - just use va_start more than once. The only time you need va_copy is to peek ahead in the middle of a run through the arguments without trashing the state, or if you're passing a va_list between functions and the called function needs to avoid ruining the caller's copy.

Comment: That's nice if all the multi-pass code can go in the outer-level function.  In my case, I put my own wrappers around stdarg stuff to allow for doing a va_copy of a partially-scanned argument list (not sure if the real va_copy would allow that), to allow for displaying a return-delimited list of lines (e.g. display two lines with show_and_wait2("Time=\205:\242\rDistance=\205", minutes,seconds, distance);).  That would likely require four or more passes through the list, and I didn't want to duplicate all the multi-pass logic in show_and_wait2(), show_and_wait3(), etc.